# Why Property Wrapper can not be applied on Global or Computed variable?

Tags: swift

I was going through Swift Documentation and it says

> You can apply a property wrapper to a local stored variable, but not to a global variable or a computed variable.

I know it is by design but just curious to know what could be the reason behind not applying the property wrapper to global or computed variable.

Comment: Re globals: The original [SE-0258](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md) proposal suggests that they intend for property wrappers to work on globals and the error message, “Property wrappers are *not yet* supported in top-level code” (emphasis added) suggests that this is merely a temporary state of affairs.

Comment: Re computed properties, as the Swift Evolution proposal points out, a property wrapper is effectively a computed property backed by a hidden, synthesized stored property, so I can easily imagine the complexities associated with a computed property that is backed by yet another computed property.